# Most efficient way to pull Last_Updated value from a table in Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, join

first post here. I need to pull the most recent value from a table, but for a given date, there are numerous entries in this particular table. I've done similar things to both options below.

Option 1..
Joining the main table to a subquery table:

```
select t1.key, t1.date, t2.value
  from table1 t1
  join
    (select key,
          date,
          max(updated_at) as last_update      
          from table2
          group by 1,2) t2
    on t1.key = t2.key
    and t1.date = t2.date
    and t1.updated_at = t2.last_update 
order by 1,2;
```

Option 2.. A subquery in the join and a descending 'order by' with a limit:

```
select t1.key, t1.date, t2.value
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2
  on t1.key = t2.key 
  and t1.date = t2.date
  and t2.updated_at = (
      select updated_at
      from table2
      where key = t2.key 
      and date = t2.date
      order by updated_at desc
      limit 1)
order by 1,2;
```

Option 2 is a bit atypical, and requires ordering of the entire table in the subquery, so I doubt it's best practice, but it works and allows the subquery to live inside of the Join, so I've used it before.

Is Option 1, Option 2, or some Option 3 the most efficient method to solve this problem? What's best practice? Happy to join after browsing Stack for a while, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This is best:

```
SELECT t1.key, t1.date, t2.value
FROM table1 t1 
   JOIN table2 t2
      ON (t1.key, t1.date) = (t2.key, t2.date) 
ORDER BY t2.updated_at
LIMIT 1;
```

For efficiency, you need an index on `table2 (updated_at)` and on `table1 (key, date)` (or `table1 (key)`, if that is selective enough). Then PostgreSQL can use a fast nested loop join.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `distinct on`.  I think this version:

```
select t1.key, t1.date, t2.value
from table1 t1 join
     (select distinct on (key, date) key, date, updated_at as last_update
      from table2
      order by key, date, updated_at desc
     ) t2
     on t1.key = t2.key and
        t1.date = t2.date and
        t1.updated_at = t2.last_update 
order by 1, 2;
```

However, I suspect that the two tables are one table.  If so, you just want:

```
select distinct on (key, date) t1.*
from table1 t1
order by key, date, updated_at desc
```